# Access Useimperativehandle method from same function

Tags: reactjs

I created a method in useImperativeHandle hook in my child component. Then, I can access it from parent component perfectly. Like below example. But, I can't access it from child component. In an other saying, **focus from parent** button working, but **focus from child** not working.  How can I do this?

[CODESANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/understanding-useimperativehandle-forked-e5qjg?file=/src/fancyInput.js)

**fancyInput.js**

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
    
const FancyInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    activateFocus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <br /> <br />
      <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.activateFocus()}>
        Focus from children
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

export default FancyInput;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import FancyInput from "./fancyInput";

function App() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FancyInput ref={inputRef} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.activateFocus()}>
        Focus from parent
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move `activateFocus`'s function declaration outside of `useImperativeHandle`, but keep the reference in it. Like this:

```js
const FancyInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  const activateFocus = () => inputRef.current.focus();
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    activateFocus
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <br /> <br />
      <button onClick={activateFocus}>
        Focus from children
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked @rateLess. Worked example at https://codesandbox.io/s/understanding-useimperativehandle-forked-c4344?file=/src/fancyInput.js

Answer (score 0):

```
  const refImperative = useRef( );
  useImperativeHandle( refImperative, () => {
    const rFuncs = {
      doThis: ( ) => {
      },
      doThat: ( ) => {
        rFuncs.doThis( );
      }
    }
    return rFuncs;
  }, 
  [
  ] );
```